# non-english character displaylike this?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate3

In my project, I am storing the non-English character in database. I successfully stored the non-English character but when I try to retrive that value, I am getting the string like below:

How to convert this? Into character?
Below is my code

```
TblNames name=new TblNames();
name.setName("அன்பு");
session.save(name);
Criteria cr=session.createCriteria(TblNames .class);
List<TblNames > tempList=cr.list();
System.out.println(tempList.get(0).getName());
```

In database it displays அன்பு but retrieving it displays ?????
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post your code for saving/retreiving...

Comment: which dbms r u using? and tell us the datatype used for that column

Comment: sql server 2014 and i use hibernate as orm

Comment: what is the datatype of column ?

Comment: in hibernate i use varchar.Sqlserver nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess. You are storing the data in `VARCHAR` datatype
change it into `NVARCHAR` and it will work.
This happend with me during storing arabic charachters

An `NVARCHAR` column can store any Unicode data. A `VARCHAR` column is restricted to an 8-`bit codepage.`

Comment: @Madhesh check collation

Comment: did u checked at table level is it stored there in non english charachters?

Comment: i am using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS this collation

Comment: @gurghet yes.. Madhesh change the collation for that column

Comment: Can you please give the correct unicode collation. I am unable to find the same. Thanks